# How to make the contents of a round-cornered border be also round-cornered?

Tags: wpf

I have a border element with rounded corners containing a 3x3 grid. The corners of the grid are sticking out of the border. How can I fix that? I tried using ClipToBounds but didn't get anywhere.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Here are the highlights of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324641/how-to-make-the-contents-of-a-round-cornered-border-be-also-round-cornered#325003) mentioned by [Jobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8091/jobi-joy)

- None of the decorators (i.e. Border) or layout panels (i.e. Stackpanel) come with this behavior out-of-the-box.
- ClipToBounds is for layout. ClipToBounds does not prevent an element from drawing outside its bounds; it just prevents children's layouts from 'spilling'. Additionally ClipToBounds=True is not needed for most elements because their implementations dont allow their content's layout to spill anyway. The most notable exception is Canvas.
- Finally Border considers the rounded corners to be drawings inside the bounds of its layout.

Here is an implementation of a class that inherits from Border and implements the proper functionality:

```
     /// <Remarks>
    ///     As a side effect ClippingBorder will surpress any databinding or animation of 
    ///         its childs UIElement.Clip property until the child is removed from ClippingBorder
    /// </Remarks>
    public class ClippingBorder : Border {
        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc) {
            OnApplyChildClip();            
            base.OnRender(dc);
        }

        public override UIElement Child 
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Child;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.Child != value)
                {
                    if(this.Child != null)
                    {
                        // Restore original clipping
                        this.Child.SetValue(UIElement.ClipProperty, _oldClip);
                    }

                    if(value != null)
                    {
                        _oldClip = value.ReadLocalValue(UIElement.ClipProperty);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        // If we dont set it to null we could leak a Geometry object
                        _oldClip = null;
                    }

                    base.Child = value;
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnApplyChildClip()
        {
            UIElement child = this.Child;
            if(child != null)
            {
                _clipRect.RadiusX = _clipRect.RadiusY = Math.Max(0.0, this.CornerRadius.TopLeft - (this.BorderThickness.Left * 0.5));
                _clipRect.Rect = new Rect(Child.RenderSize);
                child.Clip = _clipRect;
            }
        }

        private RectangleGeometry _clipRect = new RectangleGeometry();
        private object _oldClip;
    }
```

Comment: This solution here uses a converter instead of making a new class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649875/how-to-make-the-border-trim-the-child-elements  Note: i had to nest border objects to retain my colored border (background works fine without nesting)

Comment: Could you please explain the logic in your code?  I cannot seem to understand the purpose of `_oldClip` and why you are choosing the `RadiusX` & `RadiusY` to be `this.CornerRadius.TopLeft - (this.BorderThickness.Left * 0.5)`.

Comment: If you don't want to clip some types of objects (like `Canvas` in my case), you can add this control to the `if` statement inside `OnApplyChildClip()` method:  `&& !(child is Canvas)`.

Answer (score 68):

Pure XAML:

```
<Border CornerRadius="30" Background="Green">
    <Border.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Border 
                    Background="Black"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}"
                    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}"
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}"
                    />
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Border.OpacityMask>
    <TextBlock Text="asdas das d asd a sd a sda" />
</Border>
```

**Update:**
Found a better way to achieve the same result. You can also replace *Border* with any other element now.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Border1}" />
    </Grid.OpacityMask>
    <Border x:Name="Border1" CornerRadius="30" Background="Green" />
    <TextBlock Text="asdas das d asd a sd a sda" />
</Grid>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: To get rid of artifacts behind the rounded corners in the first example (which you can see when you magnify that with the Snoop tool for example) you must also bind BorderThickness (the same way) and set BorderBrush to White. This will cut off the Border's border.

Comment: The first example is more general because it can be transparent (the clipping shape does not have to be visible, with its background).

Comment: I also recommend the first example because it supports transparency

Comment: If you're using transparencies, solution 2 is a definite loser. A problem with solution 1 is that if you have a visible border (thin black line, for example), your content will spill over the line. I suppose you could apply a second border with a Z order above it. In my case, I just decided to get rid of the black line and add a shadow.

Answer (score 13):

As Micah mentioned `ClipToBounds` will not work with `Border.ConerRadius`.

There is [UIElement.Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip.aspx) property, which `Border` supports as a child element.

If you know the exact size of the border, then here is the solution:

```
<Border Background="Blue" CornerRadius="3" Height="100" Width="100">
      <Border.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Rect="0,0,100,100"/>
      </Border.Clip>
      <Grid Background="Green"/>
</Border>
```

If the size is not known or dynamic then `Converter` for `Border.Clip` can be used. See the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649875/wpf-how-to-make-the-border-trim-the-child-elements).

Answer (score 7):

So I just came across this solution, then followed into msdn forum link that Jobi provided and spent 20 minutes writing my own ClippingBorder control.

Then I realized that CornerRadius property type is not a double, but System.Windows.CornerRaduis which accepts 4 doubles, one for each corner.

So I'm going to list another alternative solution now, which will most likely satisfy the requirements of most people who will stumble upon this post in the future...

Let's say you have XAML which looks like this:

```
<Border CornerRadius="10">
    <Grid>
        ... your UI ...
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

And the problem is that the background for the Grid element bleeds through and shows past the rounded corners.  Make sure your `<Grid>` has transparent background instead of assigning the same brush to "Background" property of the `<Border>` element.  No more bleeding past the corners and no need for a whole bunch of CustomControl code.

It's true that in theory, client area still have the potential of drawing past the edge of the corner, but you control that content so you as developer should be able to either have enough padding, or make sure the shape of the control next to the edge is appropriate (in my case, my buttons are round, so fit very nicely in the corner without any problems).

Comment: Setting my grid's background to Transparent was exactly what I needed.Instead put the color on the border :)

Comment: my image still shows past the border using this code

Comment: The problem is that I want to have the top row of my grid have a different background color and have the top still be clipped to the corner radius of the border, so this one isn't workable. Good simple solution for most, though.

Answer (score 5):

Using @Andrew Mikhailov's solution, you can define a simple class, which makes defining a `VisualBrush` for each affected element manually unnecessary:

```
public class ClippedBorder : Border
{
    public ClippedBorder() : base()
    {
        var e = new Border()
        {
            Background = Brushes.Black,
            SnapsToDevicePixels = true,
        };
        e.SetBinding(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = new PropertyPath("CornerRadius"),
            Source = this
        });
        e.SetBinding(Border.HeightProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualHeight"),
            Source = this
        });
        e.SetBinding(Border.WidthProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth"),
            Source = this
        });

        OpacityMask = new VisualBrush(e);
    }
}
```

To test this, just compile the following two samples:

```
<!-- You should see a blue rectangle with rounded corners/no red! -->
<Controls:ClippedBorder
    Background="Red"
    CornerRadius="10"
    Height="425"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Width="425">
    <Border Background="Blue">
    </Border>
</Controls:ClippedBorder>

<!-- You should see a blue rectangle with NO rounded corners/still no red! -->
<Border
    Background="Red"
    CornerRadius="10"
    Height="425"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Width="425">
    <Border Background="Blue">
    </Border>
</Border>
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. Simple and reusable.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't satisfied with given answers so I came with my own solution that was inspired by [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325003/15494167).

There are two problems with accepted answer that I've noticed.

1. The boarder overrides clip object of a child element.
2. Only a uniform radius can be specified for all corners.

The problems are illustrated below:
[image]

Above you see a) Content `Grid` with a clip geometry. b) The same content wrapped in the `ClippedBorder` c) Wrapped in my `FrameBorder`

### The problems are addressed by:

1. Putting child in additional container to which the `Clip` property is applied.
2. Drawing custom rectangle geometry as default `RectangleGeometry` don't give the option we need.

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Content))]
public class FrameBorder : Border {

    private Border extraContainer = new Border();
    public override UIElement Child {
        get => extraContainer;
        set => base.Child = extraContainer;
    }

    public UIElement Content {
        get => extraContainer.Child;
        set => extraContainer.Child = value;
    }

    public FrameBorder() {
        //extraContainer.Background //uncomment to better see alignment issues.
            //= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) { Opacity = .5 };
        Child = extraContainer;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc) {
        OnApplyChildClip();
        base.OnRender(dc);
    }

    protected virtual void OnApplyChildClip() {
        var bt = BorderThickness;
        var cr = CornerRadius;
        cr = new CornerRadius(
            cr.TopLeft - bt.Left*.5,
            cr.TopRight - bt.Top*.5,
            cr.BottomRight - bt.Right*.5,
            cr.BottomLeft - bt.Bottom*.5);

        extraContainer.Clip = roundedRectangle(
            extraContainer.RenderSize, cr);
    }

    // Modified copy-paste from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19317391/15494167
    public static Geometry roundedRectangle(Size size, CornerRadius cr) {
        Rect rect = new Rect(size);
        var geometry = new StreamGeometry();
        using (var context = geometry.Open()) {
            bool isStroked = false;
            const bool isSmoothJoin = true;

            context.BeginFigure(rect.TopLeft + new Vector(0, cr.TopLeft), true, true);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.TopLeft.X + cr.TopLeft, rect.TopLeft.Y),
                new Size(cr.TopLeft, cr.TopLeft),
                90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.LineTo(rect.TopRight - new Vector(cr.TopRight, 0), isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.TopRight.X, rect.TopRight.Y + cr.TopRight),
                new Size(cr.TopRight, cr.TopRight),
                90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.LineTo(rect.BottomRight - new Vector(0, cr.BottomRight), isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.BottomRight.X - cr.BottomRight, rect.BottomRight.Y),
                new Size(cr.BottomRight, cr.BottomRight),
                90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.LineTo(rect.BottomLeft + new Vector(cr.BottomLeft, 0), isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.BottomLeft.X, rect.BottomLeft.Y - cr.BottomLeft),
                new Size(cr.BottomLeft, cr.BottomLeft),
                90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);

            context.Close();
        }
        return geometry;
    }

}
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="EndeavorWPF.ClippingBorderTest"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:l="clr-namespace:EndeavorWPF"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="201.6" d:DesignWidth="402.4">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Width="120" Height="180" Background="Black">
            <Grid.Clip>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="00,10"/>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="50,10"/>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="100,10"/>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="00,70"/>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="50,70"/>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="100,70"/>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="00,130"/>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="50,130"/>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="100,130"/>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Grid.Clip>
        </Grid>

        <l:ClippingBorder Grid.Column="1" Width="120" Height="180"
                          Background="Yellow" BorderBrush="Orange"
                          BorderThickness="10,15,20,25"
                        CornerRadius="10,20,30,40"
        >
            <Grid Background="Black">
                <Grid.Clip>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30" Center="00,30"/>
                        <!--...-->
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </Grid.Clip>
            </Grid>
        </l:ClippingBorder>
        <l:FrameBorder Grid.Column="2" Width="120" Height="180"
                Background="Yellow" BorderBrush="Orange"
                BorderThickness="10,15,20,25"
                CornerRadius="10,20,30,40"
        >
            <Grid Background="Black">
                <Grid.Clip>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="00,10"/>
                        <!--...-->
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </Grid.Clip>
            </Grid>
        </l:FrameBorder>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

### There are still some smaller issues with that:

1. Code could be optimized - generating rounded rectangle on every frame is not ideal. Could be cached.
2. If you look carefully the corners are not aligned perfectly:
   [image]
   [image]

I'm not sure why, but it looks like the actual `Border` is doing some crazy stuff and drawing ellipses instead of simply arcs - [see](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Border.cs,c3528d1bcccc5443). Note that this misalignment happens only when you have various thickness values for border edges.
I am done with this rounding issue - over half a day lost already...

Answer (score 0):

Make the grid smaller or the border larger. So that the border element completely contains the grid.

Alternatively see if you can make the grid's background transparent, so that the "sticking out" isn't noticeable.

**Update:** Oops, didn't notice this was a WPF question. I'm not familiar with that. This was general HTML/CSS advice. Maybe it helps...

Comment: But you are right that a logical answer, and it work in many situations in WPF also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to use a custom control. Created a behavior instead.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

/// <summary>
/// Base class for behaviors that could be used in style.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TComponent">Component type.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TBehavior">Behavior type.</typeparam>
public class AttachableForStyleBehavior<TComponent, TBehavior> : Behavior<TComponent>
        where TComponent : System.Windows.DependencyObject
        where TBehavior : AttachableForStyleBehavior<TComponent, TBehavior>, new()
{
#pragma warning disable SA1401 // Field must be private.

    /// <summary>
    /// IsEnabledForStyle attached property.
    /// </summary>
    public static DependencyProperty IsEnabledForStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabledForStyle", typeof(bool),
        typeof(AttachableForStyleBehavior<TComponent, TBehavior>), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsEnabledForStyleChanged));

#pragma warning restore SA1401

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets IsEnabledForStyle value for element.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetIsEnabledForStyle(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsEnabledForStyleProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets IsEnabledForStyle value for element.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool GetIsEnabledForStyle(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsEnabledForStyleProperty);
    }

    private static void OnIsEnabledForStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement uie = d as UIElement;

        if (uie != null)
        {
            var behColl = Interaction.GetBehaviors(uie);
            var existingBehavior = behColl.FirstOrDefault(b => b.GetType() ==
                  typeof(TBehavior)) as TBehavior;

            if ((bool)e.NewValue == false && existingBehavior != null)
            {
                behColl.Remove(existingBehavior);
            }
            else if ((bool)e.NewValue == true && existingBehavior == null)
            {
                behColl.Add(new TBehavior());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

/// <summary>
/// Behavior that creates opacity mask brush.
/// </summary>
internal class OpacityMaskBehavior : AttachableForStyleBehavior<Border, OpacityMaskBehavior>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        var border = new Border()
        {
            Background = Brushes.Black,
            SnapsToDevicePixels = true,
        };

        border.SetBinding(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = new PropertyPath("CornerRadius"),
            Source = AssociatedObject
        });

        border.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualHeight"),
            Source = AssociatedObject
        });

        border.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth"),
            Source = AssociatedObject
        });

        AssociatedObject.OpacityMask = new VisualBrush(border);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.OpacityMask = null;
    }
}
```

---

```
<Style x:Key="BorderWithRoundCornersStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="behaviors:OpacityMaskBehavior.IsEnabledForStyle" Value="True" />
</Style>
```