# WPF rectangle - round just top corners

Tags: wpf, rounded-corners

How can I have just the top corners rounded for a WPF rectangle?

I created a border and set the `CornerRadius` property and inside the border I've added my rectangle, but it doesn't work, the rectangle is not rounded.

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="50,50,0,0" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF5A9AE0" Stretch="UniformToFill" ClipToBounds="True"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: Why do you need the rectangle?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The problem you've got is that the rectangle is "overflowing" the rounded corners of your border.

A rectangle can't have individually rounded corners, so if you just put the background colour on the border and remove the rectangle:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        CornerRadius="50,50,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="#FF5A9AE0">
</Border>
```

You'll get your desired effect.

Answer (score 24):

Set the RadiusX and RadiusY properties on the rectangle, this will give it rounded corners

Comment: That rounds all four corners - the cornerRadius Property was removed - thus you cant do this: `CornerRadius="50,50,0,0"` you have to round all four corners

Answer (score 6):

Good example how its possible to do OnRender with DrawingContext:

[image]

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Draws a rounded rectangle with four individual corner radius
    /// </summary>
    public static void DrawRoundedRectangle(this DrawingContext dc, Brush brush,
        Pen pen, Rect rect, CornerRadius cornerRadius)
    {
        var geometry = new StreamGeometry();
        using (var context = geometry.Open())
        {
            bool isStroked = pen != null;
            const bool isSmoothJoin = true;

            context.BeginFigure(rect.TopLeft + new Vector(0, cornerRadius.TopLeft), brush != null, true);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.TopLeft.X + cornerRadius.TopLeft, rect.TopLeft.Y), 
                new Size(cornerRadius.TopLeft, cornerRadius.TopLeft),
                90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.LineTo(rect.TopRight - new Vector(cornerRadius.TopRight, 0), isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.TopRight.X, rect.TopRight.Y + cornerRadius.TopRight), 
                new Size(cornerRadius.TopRight, cornerRadius.TopRight),
                90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.LineTo(rect.BottomRight - new Vector(0, cornerRadius.BottomRight), isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.BottomRight.X - cornerRadius.BottomRight, rect.BottomRight.Y), 
                new Size(cornerRadius.BottomRight, cornerRadius.BottomRight),
                90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.LineTo(rect.BottomLeft + new Vector(cornerRadius.BottomLeft, 0), isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.BottomLeft.X, rect.BottomLeft.Y - cornerRadius.BottomLeft), 
                new Size(cornerRadius.BottomLeft, cornerRadius.BottomLeft),
                90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);

            context.Close();
        }
        dc.DrawGeometry(brush, pen, geometry);
    }
```

Information from:
http://wpftutorial.net/DrawRoundedRectangle.html

Answer (score 0):

This one will work even with Rectangle (or anything else) inside it:

```
<Border>
    <Border.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Border CornerRadius="5" Height="100" Width="100" Background="White"/>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Border.OpacityMask>

    // put your rounded content here

</Border>
```

You will have to play with Height and Width if you do not have exact size of content.