# How to style a WPF ToggleButton like star button

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, wpf-style

`appbar_star` static resource is the designed *star* from [modern-icons](http://modernuiicons.com/)

**StarToggleButtonStyle**

```
<Style x:Key="StarToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Usage**

```
<ToggleButton cal:Message.Attach="Favorite($dataContext)" Width="15" Height="15" Style="{StaticResource StarToggleButtonStyle}" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                                                    <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}">
                                                                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                                                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_star}" />
                                                                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                                                    </Rectangle>
                                                                </ToggleButton>
```

However, here is what I got from the above markup:

[image]

I'd like that the border follow along the content icon, and not be a square border. How to accomplish that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697413/wpf-rectangle-round-just-top-corners  Or maybe use a circle in place of the rectangle.

Comment: I don't get it... what does the rectangle have to do with anything? The icons from modern-icons are mostly *canvas*, so I used OpacityMask's Rectangle to place the icon and made it the ToggleButton's content. I'm open to suggestion.

Comment: Likely I don't understand what you're talking about. When you talked "Border" I assume it's coming from your Rectangle referenced and discussed and perhaps any default styling it has. Perhaps I'm confused ignore.

Comment: Are you after the visual effect (An outline), or do you want the clickable area to follow the shape?

Comment: I'm trying to create a button that is shaped like a star. That's it. If I remove the `<Border>` from the *StarToggleButtonStyle*, I'll get a button shaped like a star because I set the button's content to be a icon shaped like a star. The problem is that when ToggleButton **is not** *checked*, I want the star to be transparent with a border. When ToggleButton **is** *checked* I want the star to be yellow filled. I know how to use triggers for that, but I can't figure out how to show border around the star.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed a slightly different approach, grabbed the `Canvas` with `Path` from the resource you listed and knocked up a prototype in `Kaxaml` using a custom `ControlTemplate` (I think it's the behaviour you're after):

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Background="Coral">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.Resources>
          <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Key="AppBar" x:Name="appbar_star" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
              <Path Width="41.1667" Height="38" Canvas.Left="17.4167" Canvas.Top="18" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 17.4167,32.25L 32.9107,32.25L 38,18L 43.0893,32.25L 58.5833,32.25L 45.6798,41.4944L 51.4583,56L 38,48.0833L 26.125,56L 30.5979,41.7104L 17.4167,32.25 Z "/>
          </Canvas>
    <!-- StarButton Template -->
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="StarToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Canvas
                    Width="76"
                    Height="76"
                    Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
                    <Path
                        x:Name="ButtonPath"
                        Width="41.166"
                        Height="38"
                        Canvas.Left="17.416"
                        Canvas.Top="18"
                        Data="F1 M 17.416,32.25L 32.910,32.25L 38,18L 43.089,32.25L 58.583,32.25L 45.679,41.494L 51.458,56L 38,48.083L 26.125,56L 30.597,41.710L 17.416,32.25 Z "
                        Fill="Transparent"
                        Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="2"
                        Stretch="Fill"/>
                </Canvas>
                <!-- When checked, fill with Yellow -->
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonPath" Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
    <!-- Example Usage -->
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <StackPanel Height="25" Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <RadioButton
                    Content="All"
                    GroupName="View"
                    Padding="2"
                    Template="{DynamicResource StarToggleButton}"/>
                <RadioButton
                    Content="All2"
                    GroupName="View"
                    Padding="2"
                    Template="{DynamicResource StarToggleButton}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The important part is that we're using the `StrokeThickness` and `Stroke` properties on `Path` to provide the outline of the control; the `Fill` is transparent until the button is selected, then a trigger takes care of changing the `Fill` property to yellow when the button is toggled.

[image: Star Toggle Button]

Toggled, and Untoggled respectively.

Comment: This is great. Thanks, but how can I bind widht/height of this button? It is too big, and I tried to template binding the `Canvas`'s width/height but it doesnt work.

Comment: You would have to change the `Width` / `Height` bindings to `Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"`, `Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"`. in the `Canvas`/`Path` within the `ControlTemplate` (I believe it will only required on the `Path`).

Comment: it doesn't work this way. What I did was to wrap the canvas into `<ViewBox>` and template bind Width/Height of the *ViewBox*. Thanks.