# WPF - Setting corner radius in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles, rounded-corners, cornerradius

I want to bring a some rectangles to my WPF-Pages, these Rectangles should have rounded corners. To bring a few of the rectangles to the page without having to write every single one in xaml I decided to do it with a loop in the code.
I tried this one:

```csharp
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{             
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;

    var style = new Style(typeof(Border));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(12.0, 0, 0 , 0)));
    rect.Resources.Add(typeof(Border), style);

    Grid.SetColumn(rect, 1);
    Grid.SetRow(rect, 1);
    mainGrid.Children.Add(rect);                    
}
```

but the corner radius of my rectangles won´t change. Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: you can use [styles and templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0) for this purposes. change anything from codebehind is bad idea

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697413/wpf-rectangle-round-just-top-corners/1697460) and [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-round-the-corners-of-a-rectanglegeometry?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) should probably help you

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Just noticed that there is 'RadiusX' and 'RadiusY' like @Blindy said. This worked out well. However I will have a look at MVVMs as I don´t about it yet.

Answer (score 0):

> To bring a few of the rectangles to the page without having to write every single one in xaml

Good problem to solve.

> I decided to do it with a loop in the code

Absolutely bad solution. Use proper MVVM with an `<ItemsControl>` bound to your list of objects you're trying to display, stored in your view model. And then create a global style sheet and apply it to this either automatically or manually.

Anyway to answer your question, you're creating an unnamed style on `Border` and applying it to a `Rectangle`. That will never auto-apply, and good thing, because you reference `Border.CornerRadiusProperty` which doesn't exist on a `Rectangle`.

You want to either make your style override the `Rectangle`'s template and add a `Border` around it, then set its corner border radius, or manually add the border above the rectangle and set its corner radius in your setter (only add the style to the `Border`'s resources).

Your code doesn't really make sense to me though, `Rectangle` also has corner radius properties, `RadiusX` and `RadiusY`, you could just set those if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle is overflowing. If you do the same thing with a border it will work. When you add the rectangle inside the border you can see what its doing

```
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;

        Border b = new Border();
        b.Width = 100;
        b.Height = 100;
        b.Background = Brushes.White;
        b.CornerRadius= new CornerRadius(12, 0, 0, 0);
        b.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
        b.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
        b.Child = rect;//adding this rectangle will show you how the corner is overflowing
        grid_Main.Children.Add(b);
```