# Border overlapping problem

Tags: wpf

I have this grid with a border around it:

```
<Border Padding="0" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5">
    <Grid >                       
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

And the problem is, that the label borders overlap the orange border in the grid corners. It's probably because of the z-index. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the labels not to have a border on every side, like so

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" />
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0"/>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1"/>
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

See the following question: [How to make the contents of a round-cornered border be also round-cornered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324641/how-to-make-the-contents-of-a-round-cornered-border-be-also-round-cornered)

It'll give you a result similar to this

[image]

Use it like

```
<local:ClippingBorder Padding="0" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5">
    <Grid >
        <!--...-->
    </Grid>
</local:ClippingBorder>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the labels to have a complete outer border? If a gap between border and label is acceptable, you can set a margin on the grid

```
 <Grid Margin="2">
```