# WPF Smoothly animated ProgressBar in template

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, progress-bar

I am working on an MVVM application and I would like to have a ProgressBar that smoothly animates to it's new value when that property changes. I have seen several answers to this question using c# but I'd prefer to do it all inside the template. The problem I'm having is setting up and targeting the event and storyboard properly. Here is what I have currently:

The progress bar-

The style- (just the triggers)

```
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="RangeBase.ValueChanged">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="???????" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
                                    To="???????" Duration="0:0:5"  />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
```

I took the trigger code from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx.

How do I set the TargetName to the template itself so that it applies to all the controls which use this template? How do I set "To" to the incoming Value? There appears to be a way to grab the "Binding" value but I have Value and Max both bound on the progressbar element. How would it know what to use?

Here is the whole template for reference:

```
    <Style x:Key="ProgressStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Grid MinHeight="14" MinWidth="20">
                    <Border x:Name="BaseRectangle" Background="{StaticResource BaseColor}" CornerRadius="10,0,10,0"></Border>
                    <Border x:Name="GlassRectangle" CornerRadius="10,0,10,0"  Background="{StaticResource GlassFX}" Panel.ZIndex="10"></Border>
                    <Border x:Name="animation" CornerRadius="10,0,10,0" Opacity=".7" Background="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Border>
                    <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" CornerRadius="10,0,10,0" Background="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Border>
                    <Border x:Name="PART_Track" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10,0,10,0" BorderBrush="Black"></Border>
                    <Border x:Name="BordeCabeceraSombra" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10,0,10,0" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Opacity=".2" Margin="1,1,1,0"></Border>
                    <Label x:Name="Progress" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Opacity=".7" Content="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"></Label>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="RangeBase.ValueChanged">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="???????" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
                                    From="???????" To="???????" Duration="0:0:5"  />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Progress" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="PART_Indicator">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding>
                                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                        <wintheme:ProgressBarHighlightConverter/>
                                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource GlowFXProgressAnimated}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth"  ElementName="BaseRectangle"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="BaseRectangle"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this with storyboards in Xaml, but you could roll the behavior into an attached behavior.  The animations would still be applied from C# code, but the code would be encapsulated in a reusable behavior, and the behavior could be activated by your style(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never actually found a solution to this. I ended up just writing my own control. This isn't technically an answer to the question, but I figure I may as well post it. If someone is looking for an animating progress control for MVVM this may help.

```
    namespace Card_System.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for StatProgressBar.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class StatProgressBar : UserControl
    {
        private double _trackWidth;
        private bool _isAnimate;
        private bool _isRefresh;

        public StatProgressBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ActualWidthProperty, typeof(Border));
            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                descriptor.AddValueChanged(TrackBorder, ActualWidth_ValueChanged);
            }
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private double _barValueSet;
        public double BarValueSet
        {
            get { return _barValueSet; }
            set 
            {
                _barValueSet = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BarValueSet");
                _isAnimate = true;
                AnimateWidth();
            }
        }

        public double BarValueDesired
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(BarValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BarValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BarValueProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("BarValueDesired", typeof(double), typeof(StatProgressBar), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0d, new PropertyChangedCallback(BarValueDesired_PropertyChanged)));

        public double BarMaximum
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(BarMaximumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BarMaximumProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BarMaximumProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("BarMaximum", typeof(double), typeof(StatProgressBar), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0d));


        public static void BarValueDesired_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Set BarValue to the value of BarValueDesired BEFORE it was just changed.
            ((StatProgressBar)d).BarValueSet = (double)e.OldValue;
        }

        public Brush BarColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(BarColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BarColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BarColorProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("BarColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(StatProgressBar), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.White, new PropertyChangedCallback(BarColor_PropertyChanged)));

        public static void BarColor_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((StatProgressBar)d).BarFill.Background = (Brush)e.NewValue;

        }

        private void ActualWidth_ValueChanged(object a_sender, EventArgs a_e)
        {
            _trackWidth = TrackBorder.ActualWidth;
            _isRefresh = true;
            AnimateWidth();
        }

        public void AnimateWidth()
        {
            if (_isAnimate && _isRefresh)
            {
                double StartPoint = new double();
                double EndPoint = new double();
                double PercentEnd = new double();
                double PercentStart = new double();

                PercentStart = BarValueSet / BarMaximum;
                StartPoint = _trackWidth * PercentStart;
                PercentEnd = BarValueDesired / BarMaximum;
                EndPoint = _trackWidth * PercentEnd;

                DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(StartPoint, EndPoint, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                this.BarFill.BeginAnimation(Border.WidthProperty, animation);
            }
            else return;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the XAML:

```
<Grid>
<Grid MinHeight="14" MinWidth="20">
    <Border x:Name="BaseRectangle" Background="{StaticResource BaseColor}" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Border x:Name="TrackBorder" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" Panel.ZIndex="20"/>
    <Border x:Name="BarFill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity=".7" Background="White"/>
    <Border x:Name="GlassOverlay" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" Background="{StaticResource GlassFX}" Panel.ZIndex="10"/>
    <Border x:Name="GlassOverlayBorder" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Opacity=".2" Panel.ZIndex="12"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 11):

I think its better way.

You can create behavior to do this. (MVVM WPF)

Create class:

```
class ProgresBarAnimateBehavior : Behavior<ProgressBar>
{
    bool _IsAnimating = false;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        ProgressBar progressBar = this.AssociatedObject;
        progressBar.ValueChanged += ProgressBar_ValueChanged;
    }

    private void ProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        if (_IsAnimating)
            return;

        _IsAnimating = true;

        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            (e.OldValue, e.NewValue, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)), FillBehavior.Stop);
        doubleAnimation.Completed += Db_Completed;

        ((ProgressBar)sender).BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleAnimation);

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Db_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _IsAnimating = false;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        ProgressBar progressBar = this.AssociatedObject;
        progressBar.ValueChanged -= ProgressBar_ValueChanged;
    }
}
```

And simply usage:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE.Behaviors"

<ProgressBar Height="7"
             Value="{Binding LoadingValue}">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:ProgresBarAnimateBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ProgressBar>
```

Comment: The behaviour approach is certainly a nicer way to go. Thanks for this.

Comment: I would store a queue of requests so the animation restarts if the value is changed while animating. Not sure you can do better with the implementation as is.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is solved, but I found a really good implementation that doesn't require creating a UserControl. It imitates the "barber pole effect" and works right out of the box:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarBorderBrush" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarBackgroundBrush" Color="White" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarTrackBackgroundBrush" Color="#63D055" />

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <local:ClippingBorder x:Name="BorderBackground" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="0"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource ProgressBarBorderBrush}"
                        Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarBackgroundBrush}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Determinate" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="3" />
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarTrackBackgroundBrush}" ClipToBounds="True">
                            <Border x:Name="DiagonalDecorator" Width="5000">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="None" Viewbox="0,0,1,1" Viewport="0,0,36,34" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                        <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                                        </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#48C739" Geometry="M0,0 18,0 36,34 18,34 Z" />
                                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <Border.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                    From="0" To=".36" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:18" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </Border.Triggers>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </local:ClippingBorder>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Simply edit speed and colors to your liking.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong here, but this is a template for a progress bar with an animating background? What I was looking for was a progress bar that animated from its current value to the new value, i.e. filling up or draining instead of jumping. I'll keep this template though, thanks. Never know when I'll need something like this :)

Comment: You can probably add a StoryBoard trigger to the ValueChanged event if you want it to appear as though it's sliding to the next new value. I haven't tested this myself, but that's probably a good place to start. Good luck!

Comment: If anyone is using this (and it works beautifully), but need the ClippingBorder, go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324641/how-to-make-the-contents-of-a-round-cornered-border-be-also-round-cornered