# Crop content of rounded-corner border with image out of border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

I need to move and rotate the image outside of the rounded border

example:
[image]

In [How to make the contents of a round-cornered border be also round-cornered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324641/how-to-make-the-contents-of-a-round-cornered-border-be-also-round-cornered) find answer:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Border1}" />
    </Grid.OpacityMask>
    <Border x:Name="Border1" CornerRadius="30" Background="Green" />
    <TextBlock Text="asdas das d asd a sd a sda" />
</Grid>
```

This works if the elements do not go out of bounds.

If using rotate and/or margin like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=_border1}" />
    </Grid.OpacityMask>
    <Border x:Name="_border1"
            BorderThickness="0"
            CornerRadius="30"
            Background="Green" />
    <TextBlock Text="SomeText"
               Foreground="Yellow" />
    <Image Source="https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/rfr/logo_gmail_lockup_default_1x_r2.png"
           Margin="-5 0 0 0"
           Height="20"
           Width="55"
           Stretch="UniformToFill"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-7" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

The rounding is displaced

[image]

How can I crop the image like in the first example? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is going wrong with the viewport calculation of the VisualBrush. Not sure if that is a bug in WPF.

A workaround could be setting the viewport in absolute units, with Rectangle instead of a Border:

```
<Grid.OpacityMask>
    <VisualBrush
        Visual="{Binding ElementName=rect}"
        ViewportUnits="Absolute"
        Viewport="{Binding ElementName=rect, Path=RenderedGeometry.Rect}"/>
</Grid.OpacityMask>
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30" Fill="Green"/>
```

Or simpler, with setting the `Clip` property instead of `OpacityMask`, but still supporting resize:

```
<Grid Clip="{Binding ElementName=rect, Path=RenderedGeometry}">
    <Rectangle RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30" Fill="Green" x:Name="rect"/>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve the desired result using `Clip` instead of `OpacityMask`. Then all the elements that need to be cropped must be children of the `Border`. If your `Border` needs to be dynamic, you need to bind the dimensions of the `RectangleGeometry` to the dimensions of the `Border` using `Converter`.

```
<Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="0"
            CornerRadius="30"
            Background="Green">
        <Border.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30" Rect="0,0,500,400"/>
        </Border.Clip>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="SomeText"
                       Foreground="Yellow"/>
            <Image Source="https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/rfr/logo_gmail_lockup_default_1x_r2.png"
                   Margin="-5 0 0 0"
                   Height="20"
                   Width="55"
                   Stretch="UniformToFill"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-7"/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: Clipping works!]

[image: Clipping works!]